# Tomcat threw out "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", but heap size in dump is less than -Xmx

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

Our tomcat server threw out "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", but the heap size in dump file is only 1.7GB, and the -Xmx is 4GB.

I'm not sure what's happened, could you help me?

Environment:
Redhat tomcat6 jdk6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmxSIZE` can be greater then Java core dump because `OutOfMemory` happen when you try to allocate a large object!

Our application with `-Xmx1000m` and 670 MiB dump crashed by `OutOfMemory` on uploading 300 MiB attachment by a user.

We discover this in VisualVM in "Show Threads" trace on `System.arrayCopy`. Reference from local stack frame variable point to 300 MiB byte array.

Now we limit attachment size and save our application from future crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The Salah reply is wrong at so many levels I would consider this outright harmful.

First, the JVM will not trigger Stop The World GC and clean out heap just before dying with OutOfMemoryError. The reason for OOM is that the GC has failed to clean the memory, usually during tens and hundreds of runs prior the OOM.

Second, the recommended ratios are not actually recommended by JVM vendors. The best ratios are heavily application dependent, so without knowing what you are doing you are better off keeping the defaults than following this advice.

Comment: Yes,I can't understand why jvm threw the OOM and GC can clean the heap to 1.7GB.

Answer (score 0):

**First** you need to take a look at the following memory parameters, it may not prevent the `OutOfMemoryError`, but you should learn about them:

```
-Xmx2048m -> this param to set the max memory that the JVM can allocate
-Xms1024m -> the init memory that JVM will allocate on the start up
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -> this for the max Permanent Generation memory
```

Also and you may want to check this parameters also, those parameters will speed up the `GC` activities on your Young space, so the collection will be better.

```
-XX:MaxNewSize=  -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
-XX:NewSize=614m -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
```

also you may tell you `JVM` what type of `GC` to use like (i think this type is already enabled in the newest `JVM` versions) :

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

**Second**

When an `OutOfMemoryError` occured, the `JVM` will trigger the `Stop World GC`, so it will collect your object and the un referenced object, that why the heap size is less than you `-Xmx` value.

Usually in this case, if you analyzed this heap using one of the analyzing tools, you will clearly find the big objects that filled your memory, that will led you to the code and it will be easy to fix it.

Comment: why NewSize should be 40% , can you give some reference document which you refer.

Comment: Its not should, its recommended, Check [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

Comment: If JVM can clean up so many memory with STW GC, then why to throw OOM?

Comment: Salah, where exactly does Oracle recommend 40% of total heap to be New?

Comment: @Nikem, your first question is totally different than what the OP really asking, he ask why the generating heap when an `OutOfMemoryError` occur, because usually a full GC is triggered before the heap dump is written so it contains information about the remaining objects.

Comment: And about where the 40%, if you check the recommendation of the heap tuning, you will read this: By default, `the Application Server is invoked with the Java HotSpot Server JVM. The default NewRatio for the Server JVM is 2: the old generation occupies 2/3 of the heap while the new generation occupies 1/3. The larger new generation can accommodate many more short-lived objects, decreasing the need for slow major collections. The old generation is still sufficiently large enough to hold many long-lived objects.` i think it almost 40%.

Comment: I recommend you guys to read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html) also. Thanks.

Comment: @Salah the link you gave in first comment says "-XX:NewSize=2m :
Default size of new generation (in bytes) [5.0 and newer: 64 bit VMs are scaled 30% larger; x86: 1m; x86, 5.0 and older: 640k]" , I could not make out anything with this description. Can you throw some light on it.

Comment: Thanks, all. I'm still confused that if a full GC was triggered before the heap dump, and it decreased the heap size from 4G to 1.7 G, why JVM went on to threw OOM at this safety heap size.

Comment: @Vipin, these are the default values for for this parameter `2MB`, then it tells that they increase up the value in the newest `VMs` by `30%` larger, so its almost `640k`.